# How to discard values from a matrix (column) using specific conditions

Tags: matrix, column

EXPLANATION OF THE PROBLEM:
I have an oscillating function, defined as $f(x)$; that function is also “periodic”, with period `T` and $f(x)=f(x+T)$.
The function is also characterized by a certain number `N` of oscillations in the domain  `0  ≤  x  ≤  T`.
Moreover this function, with `0  ≤  x  ≤  T` , has a certain number of peaks and troughs (that should be equal to `N`). In this case, $f(x)$ is studied in the domain $X_{firstpeak}  ≤  x  ≤  X_{lastpeak}$, with ( $X_{lastpeak} - X_{firstpeak}) = T$ and  $f(X_{firstpeak} ) = f(X_{lastpeak})$. 
Using `FindPeaks` it is possible to obtain the values of the variable `x` at which the function reaches a peak or a trough.
the values obtained are

```
Xpeaks = {{0.12`}, {0.42`}, {0.62`}, {0.68`}, {1.08`}, {1.5`}, \
{1.96`}, {2.2`}, {2.48`}, {2.76`}, {3.06`}, {3.38`}, {3.64`}, \
{3.84`}, {4.4`}, {4.8`}, {5.4`}, {5.68`}, {5.92`}, {6.46`}, {6.72`}, \
{7.22`}, {7.74`}, {8.22`}, {8.74`}, {9.32`}, {9.74`}, {10.08`}, \
{10.44`}, {10.84`}, {11.06`}, {11.6`}, {12.24`}, {12.78`}, {13.2`}, \
{13.48`}, {13.84`}, {14.18`}, {14.80`}, {15.06`}, {15.38`}, {15.7`}, \
{16.24`}, {16.62`}, {17.04`}, {17.24`}, {17.56`}, {18.`}, {18.46`}, \
{18.76`}, {19.06`}, {19.52`}, {19.92`}, {20.5`}, {20.94`}, {21.46`}, \
{21.92`}, {22.42`}, {22.86`}}

Xtroughs = {{0.3`}, {0.46`}, {0.8`}, {1.30`}, {1.68`}, {1.79`}, \
{2.1`}, {2.38`}, {2.68`}, {2.90`}, {3.28`}, {3.46`}, {3.90`}, \
{4.66`}, {5.04`}, {5.56`}, {5.76`}, {6.22`}, {6.60`}, {6.88`}, \
{6.99`}, {7.03`}, {7.4`}, {8.02`}, {8.44`}, {9.`}, {9.58`}, {9.92`}, \
{10.26`}, {10.6`}, {10.94`}, {11.2`}, {11.86`}, {12.46`}, {12.98`}, \
{13.32`}, {13.68`}, {13.96`}, {14.44`}, {14.92`}, {15.2`}, {15.48`}, \
{16.06`}, {16.34`}, {16.86`}, {17.12`}, {17.42`}, {17.76`}, {18.3`}, \
{18.62`}, {18.92`}, {19.26`}, {19.68`}, {20.34`}, {20.64`}, {21.24`}, \
{21.78`}, {22.16`}, {22.20`}, {22.64`}}

In[8]:= First[Dimensions[Xpeaks]]

Out[8]= 59

In[9]:= First[Dimensions[Xtroughs]]

Out[9]= 60
```

As we can see the dimensions of the two columns are different. Moreover it can be observed that `Dimensions[Xpeaks]` should be equal to `Dimensions[Xtroughs] + 1`, because the first and the last value of `Xpeaks` are describing the same peak (they are the limits of the domain). And it should be also  `Dimensions[Xtroughs] = N` . 
However it seems that for a single oscillation (using `FindPeaks`) in some cases Mathematica finds more than one peak value (or “more than one trough value”). 
Ps. I can not change the options of `FindPeaks`, I just want to play with the two columns obtained.

NOW THE QUESTION IS
How can I delate values from `Xpeaks` and `Xtroughs` in order to obtain one single peak and one single trough for every oscillation?
It means that at the end, using

```
Riffle[Xpeaks, Xtroughs]
```

I should be able to obtain a column with all the values in an ascending order.
Just to be clear, 
in `Xpeaks` I’d like to delete the following values `{0.68}`, `{3.84}` ; 
while in `Xtroughs` I’d like to delete `{1.79}`, `{6.99}`, `{7.03}`, `{22.20}`.

Anyone can help me? Is there a way to delete those values automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{troughs, peaks} = 
  SortBy[
     GatherBy[First /@ 
       SplitBy[
         SortBy[Join @@ {Thread[{Flatten @ Xpeaks, 1}], Thread[{Flatten @ Xtroughs, 0}]}, 
         First], 
       Last], 
     Last], 
  #[[1, -1]] &][[All, All, 1]]
```

> {{0.3, 0.46, 0.8, 1.3, 1.68, 2.1, 2.38, 2.68, 2.9, 3.28, 3.46, 3.9, 
>     4.66, 5.04, 5.56, 5.76, 6.22, 6.6, 6.88, 7.4, 8.02, 8.44, 9., 9.58, 
>     9.92, 10.26, 10.6, 10.94, 11.2, 11.86, 12.46, 12.98, 13.32, 13.68, 
>     13.96, 14.44, 14.92, 15.2, 15.48, 16.06, 16.34, 16.86, 17.12, 17.42,
>      17.76, 18.3, 18.62, 18.92, 19.26, 19.68, 20.34, 20.64, 21.24, 
>     21.78, 22.16, 22.64},
>   {0.12, 0.42, 0.62, 1.08, 1.5, 1.96, 2.2, 2.48,
>      2.76, 3.06, 3.38, 3.64, 4.4, 4.8, 5.4, 5.68, 5.92, 6.46, 6.72, 
>     7.22, 7.74, 8.22, 8.74, 9.32, 9.74, 10.08, 10.44, 10.84, 11.06, 
>     11.6, 12.24, 12.78, 13.2, 13.48, 13.84, 14.18, 14.8, 15.06, 15.38, 
>     15.7, 16.24, 16.62, 17.04, 17.24, 17.56, 18., 18.46, 18.76, 19.06, 
>     19.52, 19.92, 20.5, 20.94, 21.46, 21.92, 22.42, 22.86}}

```
Complement[Flatten@Xpeaks, peaks]
```

> {0.68, 3.84}

```
Complement[Flatten@Xtroughs, troughs]
```

> {1.79, 6.99, 7.03, 22.2}

**Update:** Slightly more streamlined version

```
sorted = SortBy[Join@@(Thread /@ {{Flatten@Xpeaks, 1}, {Flatten@Xtroughs, 0}}), First];
deleted = sorted[[Join@@(Rest/@SplitBy[Range[Length@sorted], sorted[[All, -1]][[#]] &])]];

{deletedpeaks, deletedtroughs} = SortBy[GatherBy[deleted, Last], Last][[All, All, 1]]
```

> {{0.68, 3.84},
>    {1.79, 6.99, 7.03, 22.2}}

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks! :-)

Comment: @Nicoma89, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.